# Browser wont identify HTTP response header?

Tags: java, sockets, http

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class WebServer{

    private void run(){
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5520);
            while(true){
                try {
                    Socket serverClient = serverSocket.accept();
                    WebServerThread wst = new WebServerThread(serverClient);
                    wst.start();
                } catch (IOException evt) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException evt) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebServer ws = new WebServer();
        System.out.println("Server is up and running.");
        ws.run();

    }
}
```

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

class WebServerThread extends Thread {

    Socket serverClient;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    public WebServerThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        serverClient = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverClient.getInputStream()));
            //System.out.println(in.readLine());
            HTTP http = new HTTP(in.readLine(), serverClient);


            in.close();
            serverClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("bad");
        }


    }

}
```

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.net.*;

public class HTTP {

    String contentTypeLine;
    String file;
    String version = "HTTP/1.1";
    //String crlf = "\\r\\n";
    String statusLine;
    String responseHeader;
    String statusCodePhrase;
    String headerFieldName = "Content-type: ";
    String headerValue;
    String header;

    public HTTP(String request, Socket socket) throws IOException {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(request);
        st.nextToken();
        file = "." + st.nextToken();
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            headerValue = contentType(file);
            statusLine = "HTML/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
            responseHeader = "Content-type: " + headerValue + "\r\n";
            dos.writeBytes(statusLine);
            dos.writeBytes(responseHeader);
            dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
            System.out.println(statusLine);
            System.out.println(responseHeader);
            System.out.println("Client requesting file: " + file);
            writeEntityBody(file, bin, dos);
            System.out.println("FIle: " + file + " sent successfully.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException evt) {
            System.out.println(file + " not found.");
            System.out.println("Requested file does not exist.");
            statusCodePhrase = "404 Not Found";
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes("<HTML>" + "<HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>"
                + "<BODY>Not Found</BODY></HTML>");
        } catch (IOException evt) {
            System.out.println("Bad");
       }
    }

    private void writeEntityBody(String file, BufferedInputStream bin, DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException {

        int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int len;
        while ((len = bin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        bin.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }

    private String contentType(String file){

        String extension = file.split("\\.")[2];
        if(extension.equals("htm") || extension.equals("html") || extension.equals("txt")){
            contentTypeLine =  "text/html";
        }
        else if(extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("gif") || extension.equals("png") || extension.equals("bmp") || extension.equals("pdf")) {
            contentTypeLine =  "image/bmp";
        }
        else{
            return "application/octet-stream";
        }
        return contentTypeLine;
    }
}
```

So basically, my server listens for a request from the client, which is the browser, so if I type `"127.0.0.1:5520/test.txt"` it connects to port 5520 and requests the file "test.txt".

In terms of listening for requests and starting threads, its fine. But in the HTTP class, when my program performs these lines:

```
  headerValue = contentType(file);
  statusLine = "HTML/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
  responseHeader = "Content-type: " + headerValue + "\r\n";
  dos.writeBytes(statusLine);
  dos.writeBytes(responseHeader);
  dos.writeBytes("\r\n");
```

That ideally should create the header and the browser should identify that. But the browser is just writing all of that as if it were part of the message body.

I've tried it on several different browsers and these were the results:

- IE: Displays statusLine, responseHeader as if it were part of the message body and displays the contents of the file.
- Firefox: Throws out statusLine, displays responseHeader as part of the message body and displays the content of the file.
- Chrome: ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

I'm not sure why the browser can't identify the header.

Comment: `statusLine = "HTML/1.0 200 OK\r\n";` has to be `statusLine = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";`. --- The *protocol* is called HTTP. Sure, some responses might be *content type* `text/html`, but that has nothing to do with the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the protocol is called "HTTP", not "HTML".

Comment: thats 4 hours ill never get back